# How to get multi-monitor resolution in Process_System_DPI_Aware

Tags: winapi

I am making an addon for Firefox. Firefox is set to `Process_System_DPI_Aware`. I have handles to the monitors, is it possible to get the correct monitor rect?

All methods I tried so far are giving me the DPI of the primary monitor.

I thought to use `LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI` as it says it should work however I don't have a window to give to the function. The second monitor has no windows on it. I'm trying to take a screenshot of that desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using per-monitor dpi settings but your process is not per-monitor dpi aware. Thus, your secondary monitor has dpi virtualization.

You should perform your screenshot code from a per-monitor dpi aware process.

Comment: Thanks @David but I can't change it, I am writing an addon for Firefox :(

Comment: Indeed. So you need a new process.

Comment: Ah drats what about using `EnumDisplaySettings` to get width of screen that way?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Your code is running in a process does not support per-monitor DPI, so any settings you retrieve for secondary monitors will be virtualized.  You need to move your code to a separate process that supports per-monitor DPI.

Comment: `EnumDisplaySettings` did give me the right dimensions however I can't get the DPI/Scale factor :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create invisible window, enumerate monitors using EnumDisplayMonitors, get virtualized rects using GetMonitorInfo, move and resize invisible window fullscreen for each monitor, and get real monitor rect using LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI.